# Detect click on an image

Tags: jquery, image, onclick

I am trying to load images dynamiaclly and displaying them as shown below

```
     var uploader = $('#<%=uploader.ClientId%>').plupload('getUploader');
              uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file, res) {
              $('#<%=thumbs.ClientId%>').append("<div id=" + file.id + ">
              <a href='Uploads/" + document.getElementById("<%=currentDirectory.ClientId%>").value + "/" + file.name + "'/>
              <img src='Uploads/" + document.getElementById("<%=currentDirectory.ClientId%>").value + "/" + file.name + "' width='70' height='55' data-full='Uploads/" + document.getElementById("<%=currentDirectory.ClientId%>").value + "/" + file.name + "'/></div>");
    });
```

This is my markup:

```
  <div id="thumbs" class="imgContain" runat="server">
  </div>
```

If I do this way on the div it gives me an alert but not on the image but on the div:

```
  $('.imgContain').click(function () {
    alert('You Clicked Me');
  });
```

And I have tried using this way but it dosent give me any alert not even on the div also.

```
 $('.imgContain a').click(function () {
        alert('You Clicked Me');
 });
```

So how do I do this?

Comment: according to your markup you dont have a `a` inside div with class `imgContain `

Comment: As seen in the above uploaded bind event you can find the <a>.

Comment: Are you running $('.imgContain a').click( ... after the images are loaded?

Comment: That makes sense since the class '.imgContain' is attached to the div and not the img . Try adding the class within the img tags?

Comment: use live function instead of click. as you are adding the elements dynamically click is not binded.

Comment: post the generated markup, plz

Comment: @Somesh-It's inside the uploaded bind event as said before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you should use the `on` method

```
 $('.imgContain').on("click","a,img", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('You Clicked Me');
 });
```

Comment: @Royi-I have tried both with 'on' and as well as 'delegate' but none worked out!

Comment: @DotNetter i hope you have jquery 1.7+

Comment: @Royi-Sorry I had a mstake with my code and it worked well :)

Comment: @RoyiNamir What is the difference between `click` and `on`  like this`$('.imgContain').click(function (event) {
            console.log(event.target.id);
        });`

Answer (score 4):

It's a little hard to know exactly what your DOM looks like, but I guess you add the images to the div with class `.imgContain`. If you want to add a click event to those images you could do something like this:

```
$('.imgContain').on("click", "img", function () {
    alert('You Clicked Me');
});
```

As I believe you are adding the images dynamically, you should use the `.on()` method to bind the click event, instead of using `.click()`.

**Note** If you for some reason are using a previous version of jQuery, you could change the `.on()` to use `.live()` instead.

Comment: this wont help since img is not at the dom. you should see my answser.

Answer (score 2):

For the anchors `<a>`s  that you appended, youwill need to use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) in order to attach to it the click event like:

```
 $('.imgContain a').live("click", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert('You Clicked Me');
 });
```

Comment: @MGA-I have tried both with 'on' and as well as 'delegate' but none worked out!

Comment: The use of `live()` is deprecated, should now use `on()` as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Learn function live in jQuery. 
and use that in your code..

jQuery version 1.4.1 and above.

since the elements are placed on the html dynamically after your page is loaded. Click function is not binded.