# How to make user to like my post when they click on featured image of that post.?

Tags: wordpress, image, button

I am using wordpress for my website...i want when user click on the featured image of the post they will like the post ... like when we double click on the instagram photo's the got liked...

Answer (score 0):

A Little effort could help you to find solution faster.

1. Create a photo_likes table with several column which you need, object_id (photo id or other resources), like_count  These columns would be minimum requirement.
2. Then create an action for ajax calls. id as a get parameter is enough.
3. In action when id comes to you just select its count increment by one and update.
4. Check following link and place your ajax call instead of `alert('You Clicked Me');`
   (If you haven't any information about Ajax you can check around the internet there are many simple, complex examples )
   [Detect click on an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148409/detect-click-on-an-image)

Simply you can achieve your needs, but more professional or want to a plugin here may not be a best place to search plugins.